# how to put Arabic in my html file from database

Tags: html, encoding, sas, meta

I'm working in SAS 9.4 and I've a table in which i stored Arabic and English text in columns.

I want to print that Arabic in html SAS stored process report. I set my SAS encoding to UTF-8 and also using meta UTF-8 in head but still reports are showing ?? instead of Arabic words in my html report file.

as **example**, Lets say I've data set of name **dataset** and column name is **value_column** who has data in both English and Arabic

```
data _null_;
 file _webout;
 put '
<html>
<head>         
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
   <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>';
run;

data _null_;
 put numberOfObservations=;
 set work.dataset nobs=numberOfObservations;
 file _webout;  

 put '<tr>
        <td>' value_column '</td>
      </tr>';

run;

data _null_;
 file _webout;
 put '</tbody>
     </table>
    </body>
  </html>';
run;
```

when i run this report. it prints ?? instead of Arabic text as

```
value_column

????
??
?
file name = ???
English text
??
```

How can I print Arabic in my html report?

Comment: Try running your code in a SAS Session running with Unicode support.  Each typical English SAS installation has a start menu item for SAS(English), SAS(English with DBCS) and SAS(Unicode Support).

Comment: from where can i run SAS session with unicode?

Comment: Start menu in Windows.   In which operating system are you running SAS ?

Comment: @Richard: I have SAS Entreprise Guide 6.1. Then it is not possible to me to start one SAS session with Unicode?!!!